# is it possible for a URL to filter by tag

Tags: php, shortcode

so I have put together a function that filters products by a specific tag and displays their categories.

What i want to do, is extend it further so that when the customer clicks the category link ( that i have in the function ), and have it only show products in that category ( on the product page for that category )

is it possible for a URL to filter by tag? can i amend the url link so that it takes the tag ( I am yet to make this into a dynamic variable for the shortcode ). it's called testingtag below

```
function display_products()
{
 ob_start();

 $args = array( 
            'post_type'      => 'product', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'product_tag'    => array('testingtag'),
            );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 $product_count = $loop->post_count;

 $return_string ='';
 $start_string ='';

 if( $product_count > 0 ){
    $start_string = '<div class="woocommerce columns-4"><ul class="products columns-4">';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            global $product;
            global $post;
            $loop->post->ID;             
            $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );   
                     
            foreach( $product_cats as $collection ) {            
            $test = $collection->slug;
                if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){
                    $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );
                    $return_string = '<li class="product-category product brand_cats"><div class="banner-box"><div class="banner-box__image"> <a href="' . get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/'. 'product-category'. '/' . $test . '/' . '"';
                    glana_woo_subcategory_thumbnail( $collection);                
                    $return_string .=  '</a></div>';
                    $return_string .=  '<div class="banner-box__info"><a href="' . get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/'. 'product-category'. '/' . $test . '/' . '">' . '<h2 itemprop="name" class="woocommerce-loop-category__title"><span>' . $single_cat->name . '</a></span></h2></li>'; }  
            }
    endwhile;
    $return_string .= '</ul></div>';
 }else{
       echo 'No product matching your criteria.';
 }
  $start_string .= $return_string;

  return $start_string;
 ob_get_clean();

 }
 add_shortcode('display_products_by_tag', 'display_products');
```

Comment: Why are you using an output buffer to get the value as a string if you're going to `echo` it anyway? Shortcodes shouldn't `echo` their output, they need to return it instead. The shortcode in your question is broken because of this, and won't appear in the correct order, can't be nested inside other shortcodes or dynamic blocks, and will break several other pieces of functionality such as AJAX or REST API endpoints

Comment: hi i have changed the code - still needed to use echo within for some variables - will this still cause conflicts?

Comment: Inside the output buffers no. Outside the output buffers yes

Comment: should i find an alternative to echo for those variables

Comment: does  ob_get_clean(); not clear the content even if there is an echo used?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I have edited my code to avoid the use of 'echo'. however, it's now not functioning the same. I'm relatively new to functions and shortcodes, but i will not use something that may have side effects. I would be very grateful for your feedback, thanks

Comment: Content inside the output buffers is fine, it gets caught by the output buffers. Content echo'd after `ob_get_clean` is _outside_ the output buffer, and does not get caught by the output buffers, and will cause issues. The whole point of output buffers is to catch the output to avoid the very problem I described, that shortcodes have to return their output, not echo it

Comment: `ob_start(); echo "I am inside the output buffers I am ok"; $result = ob_get_clean(); echo "I am outside the output buffers, I will break things";`

Comment: thanks @TomJNowell. A little bit confused, so echo can be used once it is within the confines of the buffer? should the result/output be returned before or after ob_get_clean?

Comment: A shortcode cannot send output directly to the browser, it **must** return it. Output buffers catch the output, I strongly recommend that you research output buffers and what they do on php.net

Comment: will do thank you